# Cannot "Archive" static library / framework [Xcode 5]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I've made a .framework project. All is fine if I build it (it generates the .framework and I can drag it to a project and use it). The problem is when I try to archive it. I get this error:

```
cp: /Users/Samui/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFrameworkProject-byoovpxukxdtzhhjunzsucsoauqx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyFrameworkProject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include/: No such file or directory
```

If I go to the ../UninstalledProducts directory I can see the .a file, but there isn't a /include directory.

I don't know what's happening. It's driving me crazy...

Can you help me to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up bypassing this problem by converting the framework project in a Pod [CocoaPods]. Now is archiving without problems!